# How to make scoring or ranking data (as new column) from existing features on data by using ML algorithms?

Tags: python, machine-learning, ranking, scoring

Let's say the data has **10 features (columns)**, so, I need to create/make/calculate a new column as **a score or ranks** based on these features not using traditional way like z-score or normalised or scaled.
Just I am interested that **how or what machine learning algorithm (unsupervised learning algorithm) can do this?** Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One example of deriving unsupervised feature importance is using PCA. PCA would reduce the dataset to 9 features (aka Principal components). The impact that each original feature has on the principal components is easily extracted using any of the available packages e.g., [Statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.multivariate.pca.PCA.html#statsmodels.multivariate.pca.PCA) or [Sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html). Both which provide good documentation and examples on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation to use Principal Component Analysis (PCA). Yes, I know it and used several times in the project. But still, are there any or specific ML/DL algorithms that can easily bring/make a new feature as scoring/ranking from other features by not reducing them? Because unsupervised leaning algorithms can make new feature as clusters (discrete data type). So, why it can not make continuous data type?

Comment: @Yereke I hear you. And unfortunately, I can't provide a satisfactory conclusion. I recommend that you put this question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), which is another stack exchange community with greater focus on theoretical questions like yours.